# Редактирование массива обьектов knockout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockoutjs

У меня есть массив различных сообщений:

```
<!-- ko foreach: Messages -->
<div style="border:solid 1px black; margin: auto; min-height: 250px; background-color: #D1D1D1;position:relative">
<div data-bind="text: 'Podsted: ' + $data.PostedDate" style="height:30px"></div>
<div style="width: 200px;background-color: #A2A2A2; float:left; padding:5px ">
    <div>
        <div data-bind="text: $data.Author.Name" style="font-size:18px; float:left"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <div> <img data-bind="attr: { src: $data.Author.Image } " /></div>
    <div data-bind="text: 'From: ' + $data.Author.Country"></div>
    <div data-bind="text: 'Messages: ' + $data.Author.MessagesCount"></div>
    <div data-bind="text: 'Registration: ' + $data.Author.RegistrationDateeee"></div>
</div>
<div data-bind="text: $data.Message" style="width:600px;float:right"></div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
<br>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Я хочу отредактировать любое из них:

```
<div data-bind="text: $data.Message" style="width:600px;float:right"></div>
```

Вот код, модели сообщений.

```
<script>
     MessagesModel = @(new MvcHtmlString(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Messages)));
</script>


<script>
function Messages(data){
    var model = this;

    model.Messages = ko.observableArray(data);

}

       ko.applyBindings(new Messages(MessagesModel));
</script>
```

Как закинуть в контроллер и так далее я знаю, не могу только разобраться как захватить какое-то свойство обьекта(из массива), и изменить его.